# Unable to pass environment variables to Create_Function AWS SDK method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm trying to execute the following Ruby code and it constantly fails with "unexpected value at params[:environment]" error. I tried many different options for passing Hash to 'environment' parameter but it triggers the same error.

```
require 'aws-sdk'

client = Aws::Lambda::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')
args = {}
args[:role] = "some_role"
args[:function_name] = "function"
args[:handler] = "function_handler"
args[:runtime] = "java8"

code = {}
code[:zip_file] = ::File.open("file.jar", "rb").read

args[:code] = code  

environment = {}
environment[:variables] = { "AAA": "BBB" } 
args[:environment] = environment

client.create_function(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by upgrading Ruby AWS SDK from 2.6 to 2.9